Transform Entire Screen Using Windows API
I had a question about some task I've been wanting to solve using the Windows API in C++ using their headers. This is related for a project that I am working on, however at the moment I'm just experimenting with the API at the moment.
I would like to transform/translate the desktop screen by some number of pixels. This would make some things out of view in relation to the display but that's okay.
Here's a drawing I made in order to better illustrate what exactly I'm trying to accomplish:

I have read through the documentation that Microsoft provides for all the headers for their Windows API, but I could not find a function that could help with this (which I could've easily have just glanced over). If anyone could point me towards the header to read through or a specific function that assists in this I would greatly appreciate it!

I don't imagine this is a feature of windows, why do you want to do this? maybe there's a better way?

@AlanBirtles I was wanting to find a way to fix the screen after I call a different function, MagSetFullscreenTransform. This function does have some offset parameters as well, although I use those to zoom around the mouse position.

Whether you want to fix the screen offset in the monitor? Could you please tell us when will there be a screen offset? Could you please help us reproduce the issue? Whether SetMonitorDisplayAreaPosition could implement your requirements?

You could try to use SetMonitorDisplayAreaPosition function to set the horizontal or vertical position of a monitor's display area.
